# How can I have a facebook share button in listview item in android?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, custom-adapter

If I have a listview populated with objects lets say country names, and custom adapter how can I place inside a list item a facebook share button (assumming that I've setup fb account and app)

Comment: you place share button in your xml that you use for custom adapter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> list;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.share_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:text="Share" />
```

This is very short example, a lot of thing need to improve here.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare button as final variable

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
    //Declare button as final variable
final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.share_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```